# Creating installation file in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating user interface for my site.In that i create form to take input form user,
input fields are Enter Hostname,Enter database name,Enter password.
    I manage to create databse and import .sql file.But now i need hostname,database name, and password in connection file.please help me where to store that variable or how to hardcode that in connection file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand your question, you can store such details as constants, like
create a file, say **config.php** and add:

```
define("HOSTNAME", "your_host");
define("DB_NAME", "your_database_name");
define("DB_USERNAME", "your_database_username");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "your_database_password");
```

and include this config.php file

Did you mean something like this

Comment: Dear sudhir, you are right but im giving installation profile to the user and i dont want user to edit any file, Im trying to create installation like drupal.any help...

Comment: You can dynamically generate config.php file and store the database name,host name,etc into that file and try to connect to db using that detail... As you said like drupal, so checkout that open source how its installed..

Comment: Thanks sudhir and kamal for giving me valuable hint because you i solved my problem.